# What is exclamation mark at beginning of line doing in this BASH snippet?

Tags: bash, shell

I understand history expansion in C-shell and BASH, but I don't understand why the exclamation mark on the line with the `read` command is being used in this snippet from some source I'm looking at:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

. "$(dirname "$0")/includes.sh"

! read -d '' SOME_VAR <<"EOT"
  some ASCII art
EOT

echo -e "\033[95m$SOME_VAR\033[0m"
```

Why would you negate the return value of the `read` command (I think that is its effect, not history expansion)? Are there any possible error conditions, besides out-of-memory? The only one I can think of would be `EINTR`, which I think would be an abort condition (`SIGINT` or `SIGHUP`). And why would you double-quote the starting `heredoc` marker (`EOT` in this case), and not the ending marker?

It's from a major open source project, so I was guessing the author had some reason for doing this that I haven't been able to discern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `set -e` command tells bash to exit if a pipeline returns a non-zero exit status (basically if a command fails).

The `!` negates the exit status, but it also inhibits the effect of `set -e`. The idea is that if a command is being executed as part of a condition, you don't want to terminate the shell. If it's preceded by `!`, the shell effectively assumes that it's being executed as a condition (even if the result is ignored).

Quoting the bash manual:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the
>   command list immediately following a 'while' or 'until' keyword, part
>   of the test in an 'if' statement, part of any command executed in a
>   '&&' or '||' list except the command following the final '&&' or '||',
>   any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return
>   status is being inverted with '!'.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

(You're correct that the `!` has nothing to do with history substitution in this context.)

The return code for the `read` built-in is

> zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, `read` times out (in which case it's
>   greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
>   or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.

The relevant case here is end-of-file.  Redirecting the input of `read` using `<<EOT` (and disabling normal termination using `-d ''`) means that the `read` command will encounter an end-of-file, which would cause it to return a non-zero status. The `!` prevents this from aborting the script (but the value is still assigned to `$SOME_VAR`).

Comment: Thank you, I read the man page details for `set -e` but glossed over the last line. I use defensive programming, but is it superfluous here, i.e. there's no way short of `SIGHUP` or `SIGINT` that the `read` command fails?  And can you help me understand why the first EOT is double-quoted? Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer to explain how `read` can (and almost certainly will) "fail".  The double quotes in `<<"EOT"` prevent expansion on the lines in the here-doc; see "Here Documents" in the bash manual.

Comment: You're awesome, Keith - thanks again. I've come across your answers before that were helpful.